# unable to get data from the Weight Scale

Tags: php, sockets

I am new in working in integrate weighing scale machine with php through tcp/ip (LAN). i am able to open the connection but i am unable to get the data from the weighing scale machine. HyperTerminal software can able to get and list the record. i attached the piece of coding.

**Weight Machine Model - essae si 810**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
$host = "192.168.5.203";
$port = 4321;

// connect to the port
$fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr);

// don't die
set_time_limit(30);

// if connection not successfull, display error
if (!$fp)
{
    die("no connection");
}
else
{
    echo "Connection Open<br />";
    // connection successfull, listen for data (1024 bytes by default)
    $got = fgets($fp, 120000);
    var_dump($got);

    // display the data
    echo  $got;
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Output :**

```
Connection Open
bool(false)
```

**HyperTerminal Output:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sl.No MC NO        DATE       TIME      TARE   NET WT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1 123          19-09-2019 05:26    0.000    0.950
    2 456          19-09-2019 05:27    0.000    0.950
    3 789          19-09-2019 05:27    0.000    0.940
    4 456          19-09-2019 05:27    0.000   67.880
    5 1563         19-09-2019 05:32    0.200   25.390
    6 7896         19-09-2019 05:32    0.200   25.390
    7 5647         19-09-2019 05:32    0.000   25.590
    8 3418         22-09-2019 23:22    0.000   25.710
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                       0.400  172.800    0.000    0.000
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any thing i missed

Comment: Are you sure the device doesn't require a request to be sent before sending back a response?

Comment: i used this sample code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533610/reading-from-weight-scale-problems-php)

Comment: Any body kindly help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Kindly close this thread. We solved by using 3rd Party VB.NET software to pull data

Comment: You are welcome to do with your question as you please, don't put it on other people.